# Flink RichSinkFunction constructor VS open()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say I need to implemnt a custom sink using RichSinkFunction, and I need some variables like DBConnection in the sink. Where should I initialize the DBConnection？ I see most of the articles init the DBConnection in the open() method, why not in the constructor?

A folow up questions is what kind of variables should be inited in constructor and what should be init in open()?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of a `RichFunction` is only invoked on client side. If something needs to be actually performed on the cluster, it should be done in `open`.

`open` also needs to be used if you want to access parameters to your Flink job or `RuntimeContext` (for state, counters, etc.). When you use `open`, you also want to use `close` in symmetric fashion.

So to answer your question: your `DBConnection` should be initialized in `open` only. In constructor, you usually just store job-constant parameters in fields, such as how to access the key of your records if your sink can be reused across multiple projects with different data structures.